# Design: Code after "if __name__ == __main__" test

Tags: python

I want to hear an opinion on the question: Is it a bad idea to have a lot of code after

`if __name__ == '__main__':`

The reason I'm asking this is, My current project has about 400 hundred lines of code, and as it grows, I keep adding lines after above statement. So this program is expected to be about 3000 lines of code and I'm worry , that I will have too much code after this statement. So the question 'Is it a good pythonic way to write a lot of code after this statement?'

Comment: I thought the purpose of `__main__` was if you were writing a library file instead of the app entrance point. When a .py file you write is imported, `__name__ != '__main__'` and anything under your if statement is ignored. Do you really need the check if you're writing the entire app in one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there are two distinct points to make here:

- All other things being equal, it is better for readability, testability, maintainability (and perhaps some other values of "-ability") to define functions that encapsulate the behavior that is represented by 400 lines of imperative code.
- Code qualified by `__name__ == '__main__'` is *only* executed when the file is called directly, as opposed to being included as a module with `import`. So, a file like

  ```
  def be_awesome():
      pass


  if __name__ == '__main__':
     def be_more_awesome():
          pass
  ```

will only have a definition for `be_more_awesome` when provided as the source argument to an invocation of python, not when being imported. As a general rule, then, it's appropriate to put after the `__name__` test precisely the code that should be run only when the file is run as a script directly. Ask yourself these questions

- "Would it be bad for this code to run if I imported this module in another file?"
- "Does this code need to be called when I call this file directly?" (as in the case of a hypothetical `main` function that encapsulates your 400 lines)

If the answer to either of these questions is "yes", it (probably) belongs after the `__name__` test; if not, it (probably) does not.

Answer (score 5):

A simple alternative is to just add your main code into a `main()` function, and simply call it after the `__name__` check. That way, you get:

- the benefits of the `__name__` check
- the benefits of a function (which may or may not be reusable)
- the benefit of introspection (e.g. if you ever needed it, it would be easy to automatically analyze what the "main" code of a module is - it's just the `main` function!).

An example:

```
def main():
    # Be awesome here.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()  # or sys.exit(main()), if you want to return an exit code
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I would follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse your code, you shouldn't keep it after `if __name__ == '__main__'` (use this for functions/classes/modules and make the simplest call possible from this part of the program). And let me mention here the Zen of Python (two points at least matter in your case):

> Sparse is better than dense.
>
> Readability counts.